# How to change font family or size of DatePicker - React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, datepicker

The default font used in android is the default one used by android system. Can i use a different phone using styling or some sort like we use custom fonts for Text using fontFamily.

The default font i use in my app is Montesserat which you can see in calendar font but the datepicker is using default phone font.

Please check the discussion i started in the GitHub for more. https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker/discussions/297#discussion-3234793

Please help if anyone knows how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

To change font styling for react-native, it can be done by specifying a theme in `android/app/src/main/res/styles.xml`

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/DialogDatePicker.Theme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogDatePicker.Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sans-serif</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: How do I specify the fontfFamily here.. does it need to start with "@font/"? How would it look for a Custom font? Thanks!

Comment: @enerve It needs to start with `@font`, this font needs to be specified. Refer: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource